# Connecting PAL camera to pc and working with the feed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-capture

I have an ancient analog camera which has the classic PAL analog output. I want to get this feed, display it on the computer's monitor and save the stream on the pc hard drive.

I know that if it was a digital usb webcam, ffmpeg would do perfect job. So my question is: **how can I connect an old fashioned PAL camera to PC (linux), so that it could be recognised as a modern webcam?** I found [this video grabber from LogiLink](http://logilink.com/Products_LogiLink/Input_Devices_Multimedia/Video_Grabber/USB_20_Audio_and_Video_Grabber_VG0001A.htm). What is the visibility of such camera setup in the operating system? Is it recognised as a webcam (/dev/video0 in Linux case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meh, I don't know how to answer this without recommending an actual product. But ok here we go.

Generally speaking these cheap little video converters all use one of a few known chipsets and they've been around for years so Linux support is generally very good.

Also good news is that, with these basic converters, the video steam is exposed as `/dev/video0`, exactly like a webcam and that's what you want.

**A word of warning**. There are fakes everywhere that utilize unknown and potentially broken chipsets. That's where your plan might fall flat. So do your research and make sure you get a reputable device from a reputable place.

You will have a guaranteed pleasant experience if you find a device that contains the **Syntek STK1160** chipset. No firmware requirement, and Linux kernel support is solid:

http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Stk1160

Comment: Thank you for an answer. The list of [stk1160 based devices](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Stk1160) contains logilink, that I mentioned earlier. I'll give it a try!

Comment: It works almost perfectly - linux detects feed from pal camera as a /dev/video1 and I'm able to play it with ffplay. There is one glitch though. Video is in greyscale and is flickering. Just like it would on the old TV, that would receive PAL feed but would be set to receive NTSC. DO you know how can I force ffmpeg or video grabber's output to different format?

Comment: I posted this question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/885880/configure-ffmpeg-and-ffplay-to-pal-signal)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a USB video capture device with the Syntek STK1160 chipset and it works great with Linux, with no effort at all.

vlc shows perfectly the PAL video, if you set the video standard. But not ffplay, ffmpeg, avconv, ..., exactly as you mention in your other question:
[Configure ffmpeg and ffplay to PAL signal](https://superuser.com/questions/885880/configure-ffmpeg-and-ffplay-to-pal-signal)
If you have found the answer please write there, I have this problem too.

Comment: See my answer in your linked thread.

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer in my last desperate attempt just after I posted here and before you replied. I posted my answer too on that same thread.