# Configure ffmpeg and ffplay to PAL signal

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have a PAL camera and a stk1160 based video grabber, which is correctly recognised as a /dev/videoN under linux. I am able to watch the feed with vlc after setting up the video standard as a PAL:

[image]

For the purpose of my project I am forced to use ffmpeg. In the default configuration ffmpeg seems to use NTSC standard - image is in greyscale and is flickering:

[image]

**How can I set the PAL video standard in ffmpeg?**

---

Commands I'm using:

1. To view the feed: `ffplay /dev/video1`

   ```
   ffplay version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
   built on Feb  2 2015 13:40:23 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
   configuration: --prefix=/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags= L/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
   libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
   libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
   libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
   libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
   libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
   Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':B sq=    0B f=0/0   
   Duration: N/A, start: 6274.569205, bitrate: 165722 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 720x480, 165722 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
   6276.06 M-V:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
   ```
2. To record: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -r 25 -c:v libx264 ~/Desktop/output1.mkv`

   ```
   ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
   built on Feb  2 2015 13:40:23 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
   configuration: --prefix=/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/grzebien/ffmpeg/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
   libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
   libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
   libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
   libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
   libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
   Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
   Duration: N/A, start: 6143.863828, bitrate: 165722 kb/s
   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 720x480, 165722 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
   File '/home/grzebien/Desktop/output1.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
   No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
   Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
   [libx264 @ 0x23fa9c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
   [libx264 @ 0x23fa9c0] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
   [libx264 @ 0x23fa9c0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC 
   codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - 
   options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
   Output #0, matroska, to '/home/grzebien/Desktop/output1.mkv':
   Metadata:
   encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p, 720x480, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
   Metadata:
   encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
   Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
   frame=   54 fps= 53 q=28.0 size=86kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=1391.5kbits/s
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `-standard pal`

I had the same problem and I lost many days searching for an answer!

ffmpeg documentation https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html doesn't mention anything. On other pages I saw `-tvstd standard     set television standard (NTSC, PAL (SECAM))` but doesn't work. 
I found the `-standard` option when I did `ffplay -h`

Comment: It's an input option, so it applies for a video source which is v4l2 in this case. I found the solution here in [ffplay documentation, v4l2 section](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay-all.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2)

Answer (score 2):

For recording, try

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -standard PAL -i /dev/video1 -r 25 -c:v libx264 ~/Desktop/output1.mkv
```